# How to solve the following Unitary invariant measure problem ???

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be two Unitary invariant nonnegative Borel measures defined on unit ball $\mathbb{B}$ of $\mathbb{C}^n, n\geq 2$ such that: $\mu_1 (B_{t})=\mu_2 (B_{t}),$ $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}: 0\leq t <1$ and $B_t=\{z\in \mathbb{B}: ||z||<t\},$  where we denote that $||z||=\sqrt{|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+\cdots+|z_n|^2} $ with $z=(z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_n).$
 How to prove that $\mu_1 =\mu_2$ in $\mathbb{B}$  ???

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are much more likely to get an answer here if you edit your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.